# Question about Javascript pointer to an object property

Tags: javascript, object, reference

I wanted to set a variable to point to property in an newly created object to save a "lookup" as shown in the example below.  Basically, I thought the variable is a reference to the object's property.  This is not the case; it looks like the variable holds the value.  The first console.log is 1 (which is the value I want to assign to photoGalleryMod.slide) but when looking at photoGalleryMod.slide, it's still 0.

Is there a way to do this?  Thanks.

```
(function() {
    var instance;

    PhotoGalleryModule = function PhotoGalleryModule() {

        if (instance) {
            return instance;
        }

        instance = this;

        /* Properties */
        this.slide = 0;
    };
}());

window.photoGalleryMod = new PhotoGalleryModule();

/* Tried to set a variable so I could use test, instead of writing photoGalleryMod.slide all the time plus it saves a lookup */

var test = photoGalleryMod.slide;

test = test + 1;

console.log(test);
console.log(photoGalleryMod.slide);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it looks like the variable holds the value

That's correct. Since you're using number primitives, variables *contain* the value rather than pointing to it. Variables only contain references when they're referring to objects.

The way to do it is to use an object property and to point to the object — which is exactly what you have with `photoGalleryMod` and its `slide` property.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  Just wanted to make sure I did not misunderstanding this aspect of Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you're making a copy of the value, because "slide" is set to a primitive type.  Try this:

```
this.slide = [0];
```

and then

```
var test = photoGalleryMod.slide;
test[0] = test[0] + 1;
```

then change the logging:

```
console.log(test[0]);
console.log(photoGalleryMod.slide[0]);
```

In that case you'll see that you *do* have a reference to the same object. Unlike some other languages (C++) there's no way to say, "Please give me an alias for this variable" in JavaScript.

Comment: That works.  Unfortunately, slide is just a primitive, so T.J. Crowder said I already have it right.  I can't make this code any shorter.

Comment: Yes, that's true - I just mean what I wrote as an illustrative example.