# Can I create a reference to a variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I tried the following:

```
    $scope.qs = {};
    $scope.qh = {};
    $scope.qv = {};
    var qs = $scope.qs;
    var qh = $scope.qh;
    var qv = $scope.qv;
    $scope.getQuestionHeaders = function () {
        var url = '/api/Test/GetQuestionHeaders?id=1';
        $http.get(url)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
               qh = data.testQuestionHeaders;
               qs = qh[0];
```

My data is assigned to qs and I can see additional fields such as qs.i, qs.q etc. But when I use the chrome developer tools I notice that nothing has been assigned to $scope.qs

Comment: here are some stack answers about js references 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318357/javascript-pointer-reference-craziness-can-someone-explain-this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667810/question-about-javascript-pointer-to-an-object-property

Comment: *"Can I create a reference to a variable in javascript?"* Short answer: no.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct.

You're essentially doing:

```
foo.someProp = 1;
var bar = foo.someProp;
bar = 3;
```

Would you expect `foo.someProp` to be 3? If you want to update the `$scope.qs` reference, then you need to do it directly, otherwise you're just changing a local variable reference. You can modify items inside qs:

```
qs.foo = 1;
console.log($scope.qs.foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding the variables `qh` and `qs`, so they loose their previous references. You have to do this if you want to keep both vars synchronized :

```
$scope.qh = qh = data.testQuestionHeaders;
$scope.qs = qs = qh[0];
```

Updating properties doesn't affect variables references :

```
qh.witness = true;
$scope.qh.witness === qh.witness === true; // true
```